# Which language to choose for getting data from specified page?

Tags: java, web-scraping

which language most suitable for working with cookies and inner page structure with ajax?
thanks

Comment: Which language do you know best?  Also, which language do you want to learn more about?

Comment: is there example of working with sessions in java?

Comment: Do you want to build a page or scrape the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm completely misunderstanding the question, the *only* suitable language is Javascript, that being what the J in AJAX stands for.

Now, there are some web frameworks that allow you to do AJAX at a higher level, by mapping something else into javascript.  [Nitrogen](http://nitrogenproject.com/), for example, claims to facilitate "Brainlessly Easy AJAX" in Erlang.  However, at the end of the day, it's all javascript.